# User permission not routing to correct intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am making actions on google using API.AI and suddenly today my user permission request is not working. Just after the user gives permission, API.AI doesn't route to any intent. Next time when the user says "yes" or "no" then it handles it incorrect intent "permissionhandler". It rather shows some event "assistant_itent_action_PERMISSION" whereas it should be routing to intent "permissionHandler".
[image]

Here is how it should

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed now. Please check.